# Can I lock my mac volume to always be on or loud?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, macbook, macbook-pro

I want to lock my volume on my macbook pro so that i can't turn it down or mute it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with just resetting the volume to maximum periodically, run `crontab -e` (or `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`) and add a line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * osascript -e 'set volume output volume 100'
```

`*/5 * * * *` runs the command every five minutes.